# IOS - invoke a thread to send location by push notification request

Tags: ios, notifications, location, push

Can it possible to run a thread in iOS application that is running on background to send location when push notification is received?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Apple Push docs:

http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/WhatAreRemoteNotif/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html

> The **operating system receives** a push notification *on behalf of the
>   application* and alerts the user. Once alerted, users may choose to
>   launch the application, which then downloads the data from its
>   provider. If an application is running when a notification comes in,
>   the application can choose to handle the notification directly.

When the app is running in the foreground is the only time it can respond directly to a push notification. The **OS is handling the push**, displaying it, and queuing it for later user action.

iOS applications can't continuously run in the background, only for a few minutes after the app is closed (to finish a task if memory allows, for something like uploading a photo).

Comment: So how navigation applicatiions works? without running on backround?

Comment: What navigation app are you referring to?

Comment: Check out this doc [Implementing Long-Running Background Tasks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3)
I don't know what you're trying to do with your app, but you may be able to wake your app up and perform a function when the location changes. Maybe that solves your problem better than trying to act on  push notifications.

Comment: I don't want to trigger GPS location by user position, but to be able to get user location when my server is asking. can I do that on iphone or not?

Comment: I do not think so. But consider my suggestion. What is the difference between executing code on a location change vs pushing to ask the location? The server still gets the location it needs.